# How to do the transformations in Kafka (PostgreSQL-> Red shift )

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, amazon-redshift

I'm new to Kafka/AWS.My requirement to load data's from several sources into DW(Redshift).

One of my sources is PostgreSQL. I found a [good article](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/from-postgresql-to-redshift-with-kafka-connect-111c44954a6a) using Kafka to Sync data into Redshift.

This article is more good enough to sync the data between the PostgreSQL to redshift.But my requirement is to transform the data's before loading into Redshift.

Can somebody help me to how to transform the data's in Kafka (PostgreSQL->Redhsift)?

Thanks in Advance
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an article I just published on exactly this pattern, describing how to use Apache Kafka's Connect API, and KSQL (which is built on Kafka's Streams API) to do streaming ETL: https://www.confluent.io/ksql-in-action-real-time-streaming-etl-from-oracle-transactional-data

You should check out Debezium for streaming events from Postgres into Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try to learn from your link.By the way, my another source is AwsDynamoDB. Is the above same process works for that too ?

Comment: Check out the [list of connectors for Kafka Connect](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) -- looks like there is a community connector for DynamoDB, yes.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use any streaming application be it storm/spark/kafka streaming. These application will consume data from diff sources and the data transformation can be done on the fly. All three have their own advantages and complexity.